# Bash: Output from multiple commands on same line

Tags: bash

new to coding in general so I hope you'll bear with me. I am trying to get multiple commands run in succession to output data on the same line using a one-liner so I can dump into a spreadsheet and format. Not sure how to go about it or whether its possible as a one-liner. Thank you in advance!

Command:

```
 for i in `cat server_list` ; do echo -n "$i " ; ssh -q $i -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "sudo dmidecode |grep 'Version: P' | column ; cat /etc/passwd |grep -o root | column"; done
```

Current output:

```
<hostname>     Version: P00  
root    root    root    root  
<hostname>     Version: P00  
root    root    root    root
```

Desired output:

```
<hostname>     Version: P00 root    root    root    root  
<hostname>     Version: P00 root    root    root    root
```

Comment: Aside: `for i in $(cat anything)` is bad form. When you want to read a file line-by-line, this is what `while read` is for. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) going into details on how to do it right, and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) describing why the other approach is wrong.

Comment: Any recommendations for how to improve my method/s would be greatly appreciated. I typically copy and paste sets of host names into files and use the aforementioned out of convenience.

Comment: Beyond that, your remote shell on the other side of `ssh` is emitting newlines. I'd want to start by making sure it stops that; `ssh yourhost 'echo "$(sudo dmicode | grep -n1 'Version: P') $(grep -n1 -e root /etc/passwd)"'` f/e

Comment: And maybe you are trying to reinvent the wheel with `bash` for something other tools already do a better job. Since you are just starting, give it a try on `ansible`.

Comment: (suppose you could re-add `column` if you want to take out the `-n1`s)

Comment: ...or you could pipe the output of ssh into `tr '\n' '\t'` or something; that would work too, if you add an extra newline after..

Comment: And yes, I agree with @accdias, you shouldn't be building your own tools for this. *Every* piece of system orchestration software out there will already maintain an inventory for you, and most (my personal favorite being chef, though several folks I trust prefer SaltStack) will maintain it in a way that can be programmatically searched and queried (so you can do something like "run this command on all systems with BIOS version P001"); this is a wheel nobody should ever need to reinvent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your recommendation for piping the ssh command to tr '\n' '\t' worked. Thank you very much!
Any books or resources you can recommend so I can read/understand why this worked? Still getting the hang of things and I am still a ways off from getting Ansible to do this for me.

Comment: ...I really don't recommend ansible, but don't let that recommendation lead to using no orchestration tool at all! Anyhow -- the BashFAQ and larger BashGuide hosted on the same wiki it's attached to are good reading. Most immediately, wrt. why you had the problem, in `ssh somehost 'cmd1; cmd2'`, if `cmd1` is a well-behaved UNIX command outputting text to stdout, that text is going to end with a newline, so the output of `cmd1` and `cmd2` end up on two different lines.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy We actually use Chef but it seems I have a ton to learn since I did not know I could do something like"run command on all systems with BIOS version P001" like you mentioned! Time to read more on Chef. Also thank you for the explanation! Ill get cracking on the Bashguide and FAQ asap.

Comment: @ShadyYogaInstructor, ...so, with chef, where I'd suggest you start is looking at the per-node searchable data. Once you have a search query, you should be able to feed it to knife.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ill do so now.You are a gentlemen and a scholar Charles. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No worries! (By the way, it's been something like a decade since I last used Chef full-time -- these days I'm in a specialty environment where I build my own tooling -- so my memory can be potentially hazy here and there).